# Perl Regex Matching expressions without set of strings

Tags: regex, perl

I need a Perl Regex to match expressions that not have any string from a set of strings

As a example, suppose the set of strings {"red", "blue", "white"}

"A blue sky" Not matching the rule
"A green house" Match the rule

The regex `(red|blue|white)` match the rule when a string is present, but I need the opposite

Answer (score 3):

The `!~` operator will return true if a string does *not* match a regular expression:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/say/;

my @phrases = ("A blue sky", "A green house");

for my $phrase (@phrases) {
    say "'$phrase' matches the rule" if $phrase !~ /red|blue|white/;
}
```

Alternatively,

```perl
say "'$phrase' matches the rule" unless $phrase =~ /red|blue|white/;
```

or

```
say "'$phrase' matches the rule" if not $phrase =~ /red|blue|white/;
```

or many other variations.